# Split string with variable whitespace characters in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to split a string witch has a variable whitespace characters, but a get a lot of empty lines which I would like to eliminate.
this code

```
$text = "Video  Video  Audio  Audio  VBI    VBI"
$text.Split()
```

outputs this

```
Video

Video

Audio

Audio

VBI



VBI

PS H:\>
```

and I would like this

```
Video
Video
Audio  
Audio
VBI
VBI
```

**Very late edit:**
Noticed this question is still getting a lot of views, so I would like to clarify that I had no knowledge of Functional Programming or Regular Expressions when I asked this question.
All the solutions mentioned here apply as there are multiple ways to remove whitespace and create an array from a string.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use PowerShell's `-split` operator which uses regular expressions.

```
"Video  Video  Audio  Audio  VBI    VBI" -split '\s+'
```

As noted by @StijnDeVos, this does not remove leading/trailing whitespace.

Here, the `\s` represents whitespace characters, and the `+` matches one or more of them. All the more reason to go with @user3554001's answer.

Another option is to filter the empty strings.

```
 "Video  Video  Audio  Audio  VBI    VBI".split()| where {$_}
```

Comment: `-split '\s+'` doesn't remove leading and trailing whitespace, so you still need to filter out empty strings.

Answer (score 28):

you can use this snippet to eliminate empty lines :

```
$text.split(" ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a tab in between the strings.

Comment: @randomuser15995183 it does if you specify tab character `"\`t"`. Try this, press Ctrl-J to break a line. [char]9 is a Tab char: `"1 2
$([char]9)3
4".split(" \`n\`t",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 25):

`-split "Video  Video  Audio  Audio  VBI    VBI"`

Comment: +1 I prefer this to my own answer. I forgot `-split` could be used as a unary operator.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it replaces more than one instance of a space with a single instance before carrying out the split command:

```
$($text -replace '\s+', ' ').split()
```

Answer (score 2):

The -split operator takes a regex argument, so just match multiple whitespace characters (\s+):

```
$Text = $text = "Video  Video  Audio  Audio  VBI    VBI"
$text -split '\s+' -match '\S'

Video
Video
Audio
Audio
VBI
VBI
```

Any trailing whitespace after the last one may leave you will a null entry, so the -match will eliminate anything that is only whitespace.

Comment: `k get replicasets | %{$_.split(" ") -match "\s"}`

Answer (score 1):

other solution :

```
$text -split ' ' | where {$_.Trim() -ne ''}
```

or :

```
$text.Split(' ').Where({$_.Trim() -ne ''})
```